# Sanitize output in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter in my project. I have lots of data with special characters like quotes(',"). While we printing them in a form within some JavaScript functions dynamically, it is breaking the JavaScript functions. So is there any way to sanitize(expecting something like doing addslashes() with all the output data) all the output that is coming through codeigniter query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `quotes_to_entities()` to alter the quotes to html entity

[view it here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html)